# Batch Missing Operand RANDOM

Tags: batch-file, random

So I have too Random number generators;

```
SET /A answer=%RANDOM% * %mode% / 32768 + 1,
SET /A resp=%RANDOM% * 5 / 32768 + 1,
```

then those make it say `Missing Operand`. I have tried the code with `@echo` set to on, but I didn't see anything wrong. Really there is nothing wrong with my code it just says `Missing Operand`, which is really annoying since its not helping.

So I either need a way to hide the Error message or a way to prevent it from having the error...

- *Note that I do have the* `%mode%` *set ahead of time, but I don't have* `%RANDOM%` *because I don't think it would be random anymore.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that comma at the end of the SET commands

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Batch Missing Operand RANDOM - D3F4ULT
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "mode=13"

SET /A answer=%RANDOM% * %mode% / 32768 + 1
SET /A resp=%RANDOM% * 5 / 32768 + 1

echo mode   = !mode!
echo answer = !answer!
echo resp   = !resp!

pause
exit
```